# Function is either nowhere zero or a constant function.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, proof-explanation

> Hurwitz's theorem:
>
> Let $\{ f_n\}$ be a sequence of analytic functions on an open set $D$, which converges uniformly to a function $f$ on compact subsets of $D$. If the functions $f_n$ are nowhere zero, then $f$ is either identically zero or nowhere zero.

> Proof by contradiction:
>
> Suppose $f (z) = 0$ for some $z ∈ D$ and that $f(z) \not \equiv 0$. Take a small curve $\gamma \subset D $, centered at $z$, then $f(z) \neq 0$ on $\gamma$. Thus,
> $$
> \frac{f'_n}{f_n} \to \frac{f'}{f} \text{ on } \gamma
> $$
> and therefore,
> $$
> \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{f_n'(z)}{f_n(z)}dz=0 \tag{*}
> $$
> However,
> $$
> \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz \geq 1
> $$
> according to the argument principle. Thus, we have a contradiction and therefore $f(z) \equiv 0$ or nowhere zero.

**My question is** whether the above proof for Hurwitz's theorem shows that it satisfies constant functions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the theorem applies to functions that are either identically zero or nowhere zero. Any constant function is either the zero function (identically zero) or not the zero function (nowhere zero).

Comment: how is a constant function identically zero/zero function? (sorry it might be a dumb question but f(z)=3 is not the same as f(z)=0?)

Comment: So if the function is of the form $f(z)=c, c \ne 0$, then it is nowhere zero. If the function is of the form $f(z)=c, c=0$, then it is identically zero. Those are the only two types of constant functions (the zero function and all other constant functions).